# how wanam exposed work?

Tags: xposed-framework

I have a Samsung phone which is rooted and has xposed framework. There's an app "wanam exposed" it's runs using an xposed module. It can change themes of stock Samsung ROM. It can change color of notification bar, and almost anything. I want to ask that does it modify any configuration files? If so then what's the locationof those files? And all is changes can be reversed just by disabling the module in xposed app and restarting. How is that possible?

Comment: Wanam Xposed is an Xposed module. The magic is performed by framework it uses. A brief can be found here: http://repo.xposed.info/module/de.robv.android.xposed.installer Details are here: https://github.com/rovo89/XposedBridge/wiki/Development-tutorial#how-xposed-works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just published a blog article on that yesterday you might wish to read: [Xposed: The mighty Android toolbox](https://android.izzysoft.de/articles/named/xposed-intro). Amongst others, it explains some background on how Xposed works.

Basically, the framework modifies the [dalvik](/questions/tagged/dalvik) cache at boot time (or the corresponding [art](/questions/tagged/art) stuff on Android ≥ 5). So all changes take place on boot. Thus enabling/disabling modules only shows changes after rebooting the device: if you disable a module, it's changes simply won't be applied the next time you start your device.